# Component based clientlibs AEM

Tags: javascript, css, performance, aem, client-library

Is it better to split up clientlibs by components if it means more calls to the server?

I.e. using

`<%@taglib prefix="ui" uri="http://www.adobe.com/taglibs/granite/ui/1.0" %>
<ui:includeClientLib categories="mqd.component.accordion" />`

in the `<component>.jsp` instead of compiling all the CSS in a single stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, this is more of a decision based your use case, there is no one approach which fits all the scenarios -

**Loading CSS at component level**

When you load CSS at the component level, it is not available in the HEAD section when the page rendering process kicks off. It will only render your component CSS when it encounters it somewhere in the body tag.

Conditionally loading CSS based on the component is not available by default, you would have to write custom logic to achieve this. 
From [this](https://forums.adobe.com/message/10357790#10357790) post,

> One way to achieve this is to intercept that behaviour. Use a filter
>   and buffer all data written to the output buffer in memory. Then you
>   can render safely all components and if you encounter your special
>   component you can set a flag in the request attributes. The filter can
>   then check for these attributes, change the buffer accordingly and
>   then send everything out. That approach is a bit risky, because it
>   *can* consume a lot of memory. And it changes the rendering performance and behaviour of your page. But it might be worth a try.
>
> Also, with component level CSS, you would have to ensure the styles
>   for a component don't affect styles for another component, i.e. you
>   would have to use narrow selectors to do this and ensure you don't
>   break anything else in the process.

Also, with component level CSS, you would have to ensure the styles for a component don't affect styles for another component, i.e. you would have to use narrow selectors to do this and ensure you don't break anything else in the process.

---

**Other approaches**

**Using page components** - If you have a component which has a lot of styles and you don't want this to get loaded on every other page, you can look at using page components(different templates) to achieve this. Each page component can load a different group of clientslibs based on its use.

**Using deferred clientlibs** - If your layout constantly changes and you’re worried about how big your clientlibs file has become, deferred clientlibs might be a better option. Example from the link listed below -

```
… [Navigation component logic]

<ici:js-defer>

<cq:includeClientLib js=”icidigital.components.navigation”/>

</ici:js-defer>

[Navigation component end]

… [Sitemap component logic]

<ici:js-defer>

<cq:includeClientLib js=”icidigital.components.siteMap”/>

</ici:js-defer>

[Sitemap component end]

becomes…

<div class=”footer” />

<script type=”text/javascript” src=”path/to/programmatically/combined/deferred/clientlib.js”></script>

</div>
```

Whatever approach you take, ensure caching, page load times, maintenance, performance, etc are taken into account.

---

**Further read**

[Best approaches to clientlibs in AEM](https://www.icidigital.com/blog/web-development/best-approaches-clientlibs-aem-part-3)

[CSS best practices in clientlibs](https://www.icidigital.com/blog/web-development/css-best-practices-aem-part-2)

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough and helpful answer!